# Why is visible="false" not working for a plain html table?

Tags: html, html-table, visibility

The visible property of html table does not work.

Why do they have that property if its defective? I had to use `style="visibility:hidden"` in order to hide a table.

Please explain why. I am very curious

Here's the code I'm using. The intention is to hide the table as a whole but its not hiding the table or the controls inside it

```
<table visible="false">
  <tr>
    <td >
      <label>Pick the color for action needed and paste it on textbox</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Apply color" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Post all your relevant code. I'm able to get this inline style working with a table.

Comment: @CCRicers I am curious to see your working code

Comment: @Leon http://jsfiddle.net/SgKXY/1/

Comment: @CCRicers where is the visible="false" property in your code? oh, you got it working with "inline style"... sorry, I was talking about that `Visible` property ;-)

Comment: I have added the code to the original post. Please help me by looking at it

Answer (score 28):

Use `display: none` instead. Besides, this is probably what you need, because this also truncates the page by removing the space the table occupies, whereas `visibility: hidden` leaves the white space left by the table.

Answer (score 18):

You probably are looking for `style="display:none;"` which will totally hide your element, whereas the visibility hides it but keeps the screen place it would take...

UPDATE: `visible` is not a valid property in HTML, that's why it didn't work... See my suggestion above to correctly hide your html element

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what the OP asked about.

Comment: I thought it was only one (mine, before you updated:)). I think you others got it wrong because the OP says he had to use `visibility:hidden` instead of "defective" visible, but he didn't complain about its behavior.

Comment: I guess "the tone makes the sound", as they say ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want use it, use `runat="server"` for that table. After that use `tablename.visible=False` in server side code.

Comment: Although the question does not state it, the `visible` attribute is a [.NET specific server side syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165313(v=vs.90).aspx) for preventing the node to be rendered in DOM. Thus this is a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

For a similar post a long time ago there seems to be issues with making table visibility hidden.

You have two options, one is to use the `display:none` attribute.

Or two wrap the table in a div and make the div hidden.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="visibility:hidden">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Content
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

visibility:hidden is the proper syntax, but another way to 'hide' the table is with display:none or dynamically with JQuery:

```
$('#myTable').hide()
```

Comment: `display:hidden` doesn't exist, hidden is not a valid value

Comment: Leon display hidden is not a valid attribute, it will either be display none or visibility hidden.

Comment: @aspect that's exactly what I wrote

Comment: @aspect, that's what Leon said :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker you got me on Text2Speech? I hope I don't sound too scary ;-)

Comment: @Leon, no that was fully controllable text2speech brain builtin :)

Answer (score 1):

For the best practice - use `style="display:"`

it will work every where..

Answer (score 0):

Who "they"? I don't think there's a `visible` attribute in `html`.

Comment: +1: A bit rough explained, but right. There isn't such an attribute. And almost like many others here really adressing the OP's question.

Comment: @Fatal, well, but I didn't really insult anyone, I hope :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that visible="false" does not work is because HTML is defined as a standard by a consortium group.  The standard for the Table element does not have a visibility property defined.

You can see all the valid properties for a table by going to the [standards web page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2) for tables.

That page can be a bit hard to read, so [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) is a link to another page that makes it easier to read.